# Windows Backup job fails

Tags: backup, tape, tapedrive

I currently have a server configuration that allows me to schedule backup jobs and copy the specified folders to tape backup on 4MM DDS tapes. Unfortunately this is my first experience with tape backup. (old school I know). However, I successfully set up a job to run on a schedule and I have inserted the tape into the tape drive and have manually cleared the data. Whenever I go into the backup utility and select the job I want it to run I get the following message...

There is no free media available with the selected type.
Add unused media or click Cancel to end the operation.
Note: It may take up to 60 seconds to recognize new media.

The report on the failed status comes up with the following...

Cannot locate the specified media or backup device. This backup operation will terminate.

I am confused as to why the files are not being copied over to the tape backup even after I have removed all data from the media.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't mention what backup spftware you have but given what you'd said, my money is on the media not being in a free pool of backup media.  Tape backup software generally has a retention rule of some sort.  These rules apply to the media ID of the tape and govern how long a particular tape cannot be overwritten.  Even if you delete the data from the tape (and in some cases even if it's formatted) the media ID remais the same and the tape cannot be used.  You need to somehow move that tape ID into a free media pool in order to write data to it.